# What do I lose by not booking flights through a travel agent?

Tags: air-travel, travel-agents

I take quite a lot of flights for both business and pleasure, and although I typically book my business flights through a (corporate-mandated) travel agent, I always book my personal flights directly with the airline (I should add that I am fussy, and I normally fly only with full-service airlines; no budget ones for me).

From time to time, I read that booking flights through a travel agent, either online or physical, can lead to cheaper prices. At least for simple trips (one airline, maybe a simple return), I have a hard time believing this to be the case; the airline has most direct control over their tickets, travel agents add a layer of extra indirection that has to be paid for, etc.

So am I losing anything by not booking with a travel agent? Am I really likely to get better prices?

*Edit*: I should be clearer - let me restrict the scenario by imagining that I already know what I want - e.g. to get from LHR to ORD on date X/Y/Z, with no stops, ideally on American Airlines. Can a travel agent still offer me something in that scenario?

Comment: One thing to note is that some things may actually be *lost* by booking through an agent, particularly if they book you at a group rate. Group rates often do not allow you to pick your seat, earn miles, or check-in online in advance. Last year, I traveled as part of a group that the leader of the group booked via an agent and all of the above happened. Since we were not able to choose seats, we got whatever was leftover, which meant I was stuck in a middle seat for nearly 22 hours one way and earned no miles for flying halfway around the world and back.

Comment: Booking online via the airlines' websites definitely took more time researching the options when I took a similar trip this year, but it was a much more pleasant journey as a result (and I did get my miles.)

Answer (score 19):

In the UK, one major thing you lose by not using a travel agent is [ATOL protection](http://www.caa.co.uk/default.aspx?catid=1080). This may not be relevant if you're not booking hotels though the agent ([did you recieve an ATOL certificate?](http://www.caa.co.uk/application.aspx?catid=14&pagetype=65&appid=7&mode=detail&nid=2380~)). But if you do and the airline goes bust while you're away ATOL will:

> ...make sure you can finish your trip and return home. If your
>   holiday is booked but you have not yet left, you will usually receive
>   a refund.

[Source](http://www.caa.co.uk/default.aspx?catid=1080)

Booking directly, you may lose all your money or have difficulty returning home. I'm not sure if similar schemes run in other countries.

---

The main advantage of ATOL protection over travel insurance:

- ATOL protection will cover you if your provider goes bust; many
  travel insurance policies don't include this.
- if you book with an ATOL accredited agent, ATOL will have completed due
  diligence against that agent - the idea being that it isn't about to
  fail imminently.
- If you book a holiday and the **airline** fails **before you travel**
  the ATOL-protected tour operator **must** make alternative flight
  arrangements for you. Often Travel Insurance will refund you the money but it will be down to you to book any alternatives, etc.

All ATOL Accredited agent **must** provide the above. There is a small additional cost that the agent must pay to ATOL (I think it's about 80p); this may or may not be passed on to the customer.

Comment: But the ATOL "insurance" is funded by the travel industry, which means it is paid by the travellers themselves...  Like any insurance plan...

Comment: @User58220 and that's a pretty good thing.

Comment: @User58220 Working for a travel agent I can tell you that ATOL protection add's roughly 80p to your booking...

Comment: Personally, I'd consider the chance of Delta or Southwest, not only going bankrupt, but ceasing operations and liquidating before my date of travel to be sufficiently small to not be worth paying any extra cost to protect against. If you're flying with some small, no-name carrier, then this might be a real concern worthy of insuring against (especially if the ticket is expensive, such as if you booked flight on, say [Virgin Galatic](http://www.virgingalactic.com/booking/).)

Comment: @reirab There are other airlines that are suddenly in serious financial difficulties (such as Malaysia Airlines which is looking to [delist](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2014-08-08/malaysia-airlines-faces-painful-steps-after-429-million-buyout.html)).  Even then,  Delta was in bankrupcy from September 14th 2005 through April 30th, 2007. There were [quite a few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_bankruptcies_in_the_United_States) US airlines that discontinued passenger operations in 2008 and airlines have continued to be discontinued and sometimes liquidated.

Comment: ... and there is a [very impressive list of defunct airlines of Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_defunct_airlines_of_Europe) and [United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_defunct_airlines_of_the_United_Kingdom) for those on that side of the pond.

Comment: @MichaelT The ones on that list that actually ceased operations were, with the exception only of Aloha, all the tiny airlines for which I said this protection might actually be a good idea. It's been a long time since a major U.S. airline has liquidated, though. Most of them have been through bankruptcy, but that was Chapter 11 restructuring with almost nil chance of ceasing operations, not Chapter 7 liquidation.

Comment: @Michael So it takes two extremely high-profile plane crashes in the span of a few months to bring a relatively major airline.. not really that close to ceasing operations? I'd say that's actually the best example of why there's really no reason to worry if you don't book on small airlines.

Comment: This became big news in the UK a couple of summers ago when are largish low cost carrier went under at the height of summer, it stranded lots of people abroad (who were on their summer holidays). Many people found their travel insurance didn't cover them and they had difficulty getting home. I think the government stepped in in the end.

Comment: If your airline goes bankrupt, you can typically get your money back through your credit card company - _the airline did not deliver what you paid for_. You might still be stuck in Lalaland, but at least you have your money back.

Answer (score 16):

I can't list all possible things you might lose by not booking through travel agents, but I know one or two for sure, in regards to cheaper prices.

Airlines do sell seats in bulks, same as in manufacturers sell goods in bulk, these bulk seats will be cheaper and customers to these bulk seats are travel agents. This type of seats are called [consolidated tickets](http://wikitravel.org/en/Airline_consolidators). These seats are a win-win situation for both airlines and travel agents. For the airlines, these seats are sold and got paid for, whether the seats are resold by the travel agents or not, and for the travel agents, these seats are cheaper which will help them to attract more buyers, that's why you see some agents show prices cheaper than what is shown in the operators website or in another agent's pricelist. So even if you are sure you want to go using a specific airline, you might get a better price from a travel agent than what you might get from the operator itself.

Other possible thing you might lose is the "more options", and I am not talking about prices here. When you book through a travel agent, you will have more options from different airlines and you got to choose, some of these options might have nice transit cities in the middle, which might give you the chance to see other cities in the way to your destination, or possible other packaged deals which comes with a cheap tour offer or a cheap accommodation. These options are not available when you book directly from the airline's website, they will only show their own flights.

Comment: OK - I should have been clearer and pointed out that in most cases I'm pretty confident that I already know what I want - I've looked for it on matrix.itasoftware.com or similar. Will the travel agent get me a better price in many cases, or any other non-obvious benefits?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier I have made an edit now to clear that point, it is not showing as an edit because I did it in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: If you fly often in the same route and/or you are strict about the date, airline, ticket class (even economy has multiple fare classes - some give you 50% of miles, etc), I think the better way would be to use the Airline web site. Those bulk tickets agents sell usually comes with some restrictions. I used a few airlines in the past, but I had hard time claiming miles for those flights. For flights with stopovers, etc, agents can be handy.

Comment: Ayesh K, agreed. That's always been my concern - if I'm specific about what I want/need, the travel agent can't offer me much, as their only real advantage is a greater "diversity" of flights.

Comment: "these seats are cheaper which will help them to attract more buyers" except the agent now has to also make you pay for those seats they weren't able to sell.

Comment: @david, a reference?

Comment: @MeNoTalk: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_sense . There you go, if you buy something and can't sell it you have to pay for it yourself. If your job is to be an agent your money comes from your customers. If your customers buy things from you you thus have to charge a surcharge to pay for the seats he wasn't able to sell.

Comment: Sorry @David, you make no sense at all. Your comment is just an assumption, travel agents do provide better prices in most cases and that's it.

Comment: If the [number of empty seats times their price] over [the profit per seat times the total number of seats sold] is less than the margin by which seats are cheaper when bought in bulk then indeed the price can be better (not including the sallary of the agent and profits the agents has to make), if not it has to be more expensive. That's no assumption, that's just plain simple logic.

Comment: I think there is a difference whether the agent is online-only or a traditional agent. Online agents are using flight reservation systems (amadeus for e.g) and AFAIK, they don't buy bulk tickets in advance.

Comment: @AyeshK not really true, check [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19339/huge-difference-in-price-between-online-travel-agents-and-airline-website)

Comment: I didn't really know. I use one UK online agent and a traditional one here in my city. Only the traditional one gave me cheaper ones while the online one gave almost similar prices. Thanks for the link @MeNoTalk

Comment: AFAIK, QA doesn't sell bulk/consolidated tickets. Their offices only know abouth the availability of the flight but not the prices.

Answer (score 6):

The biggest difference between doing it yourself on an airline's website and going through through a travel agent is less flexibility.  The travel agent's reservation system shows them how many seats in each fare class, allowing them to build your booking flight by flight.  The airline system uses algorithms that cover many possibilities, but not all.

So an experienced agent can perhaps build you an itinerary from A to B, that the airline algorithm isn't programmed for.  But likely not at a better fare.

Consolidator fares and bulk fares are slowly becoming a thing of the past except for tour companies that package air & land. Most of these fares are no better than the best airfare that the airline offers to the public, but perhaps have more seats available per day.

Comment: I was going to make the comment about cons fares disappearing below but you beat me to it. Most airlines are actively trying to cut travel agents out of the loop these days (as Low cost carriers did) to reduce their gross prices to the customer.

Comment: The experience is also a good point, someone who can natively use Galileo gets much more control, etc. than any automated system can.

Answer (score 4):

Booking with a single airline puts the onus on them if a leg is delayed so long that you miss a connection.

If you book a journey on multiple airlines (eg to China and then within China can easily make a change of carriers a good choice) then if you make the bookings yourself separately you may not be covered for a missed leg in the case of a delay. Subject to certain limitations a travel agent is able to offer protection against such events. This may require that the airlines involved are involved in the same 'conference'  such as eg Star alliance, but may not, and agents will usually (but not always) offer journeys where this protection does apply.

I once was almost a day late for an internal Australian QANTAS flight due to a China-Australia non-QANTAS delay. I had booked the last leg myself independently from the main journey and notionally lost the right to a new flight within Australia. On that occasion QANTAS kindly provided a 'free' replacement flight, but were not obliged to do so.

Comment: Something to take into account but note that “different airlines” is not the same as “booked separately”. It's possible to book flights on different airlines as one ticket and it's also possible to independently book two tickets on the same airline and be stuck for this reason.

Comment: Fancy that -  a downvoter. +4 -1. Who can fathom the minds thereof?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon fancy that, a complaint about downvotes. +5 -2.

Comment: The question says “travel agent,” not “single airline.”

Comment: @WGroleau Yes. But my answer covers it. |The answer is "graduated". The first paragraph (one sentence) covers the simple "book with one airline scenario". Similar results whether with an agent or direct. Price can be a major factor. || The second paragraph compares the "book with agent" versus "self book with multiple airlines" scenario. Here "self book with multiple airlines' is what could have cost me a fare as the flight sequence with one airline was covered against delays but changing to the 2nd airline wasn't. If I'd booked with an agent I'd have (probably) been covered. | Yes?

Answer (score 3):

A few years ago (online) travel agents would pretty much always offer lower price than the airline on its website (e.g. British Airways). At some point it seemed to change though, and now many airlines (including BA), but by no chance all, make sure that their online prices are not worse than the agents. I am not sure what is American Airline's approach. Websites like [Kayak](http://kayak.co.uk) allow you to compare prices in one place, because they index both main online agents as well as the airline's themselves.

Given that the price is the same, I don't think you loose anything by booking with the airline. A thing you definitely gain, is the lack of agent's fees when you want to change your booking. A few years ago I had a ticket booked with one of the online ones and I had to cancel it. The agent called the airline on my behalf and then charged me £25 per person fees *on top* of the fees of the airline. To make things more annoying, these fees are usually not covered by your travel insurance.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that I get from a travel agent that I have yet to find from an airline website is ticket *reservation* without *paying for it*.

In other words, I want to hold a seat for me now, because I might be traveling on future date *X*; lets say its four days from now.

If tomorrow I decide to cancel my trip, I can cancel and then do the refund process through the airline's website - which then has to talk to my bank and there may be charges etc. etc.

However, with an agent - I just call him up and say "I changed my mind" and the will just cancel the booking, that's it - I don't lose anything because I haven't yet paid for the reservation.

I also cannot manage to book an "open ended" ticket through the airlines I fly (usually, Emirates) from their website. An open ended ticket is a two-way ticket with an open return date.

If you have a good relationship with an agent (you use the same one consistently), they can save you a lot of hassle and time when you need something urgent.

I once had to travel the same day (it was an emergency). I rushed the airport and stood in line at the check-in counter, and called my travel agent. By the time it was my turn at the queue, my ticket was waiting for me with the agent. He had also managed to secure me a hotel at my destination.

I always remind myself to throw some business to my travel agent, he isn't always the cheapest compared to booking direct with the airlines, but more than makes up for it in terms of service.

Comment: Most US airlines will allow you to hold the ticket for 24 hours before paying when booking through their website. I know, for example, that American Airlines does this.

Comment: Also, how long does the agent give you the hold for?

Comment: I once did a hold for two weeks - ie, I told him today to book me a flight two weeks for now; then decided not to travel.

Comment: Burhan, I assume he must be buying consolidated seats as discussed in some of the answers above, and therefore have already paid for them himself. I very much doubt any airline would allow him to hold a seat for two weeks on their inventory.

Comment: Yes I believe so; but this was not during a busy travel season (like summer holidays or winter/christmas) when to my knowledge these seats are typically bulk reserved. I just called him to ask - he told me that he actually reserved an open ticket (held it) - that way he can change the dates around; and then at the time of booking he can switch the ticket type. He also mentioned that this doesn't always work because sometimes the ticket type is not available on a segment. Anyway, good to have a travel agent on your speed dial.

Comment: Ah, OK. Open/flexible tickets - sure - you can change/cancel these whenever you like anyway. But they are typically the most expensive ticket type.

Comment: Yeah what my agent does is he books these, but then when I want to travel he converts the reservation to the normal ticket.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That is not always guaranteed to work as the different fare buckwets have separate inventory. Ie the sale fares could sell out while you hold onto your flexible fare. At the very least, the sale fares are likely to increase in price.

Comment: 5+ years on. -> Be **CERTAIN** that the booked seats are BOOKED and not a paper phantasm. Once we found out on the day that we were due to travel that the impressive paperwork that we held did not in fact constitute bookings or tickets. The agent had absconded with our money. On that occasion we rebooked a multi destination international holiday, missing out only one destination (Hanoi), added Brunei, managed Hong kong, China internal and Singapore (different order) and left 2 hours late. We got our money back latterly. Others were subsequently not so lucky :-(.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is short and simple: when I tried to buy a ticket for my forthcoming flight on date X/Y/Z (other dates was less convenient) there was already no tickets by airline. However one of travel agents have one remaining ticket (with almost the same price). So sometimes travel agents can give you more possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Flight booking websites tend to push connecting flights via hub, even if there are also multiple direct flights between your airports.

For instance, check your favorite website trying to book a return flight between Zurich and Frankfurt. At least five direct flights daily are offered by Lufthansa alone, in both directions. However many booking sites will suggest connecting flights with long layovers instead. These may be cheaper than direct flight, but not very significantly, much less than the difference between Business and Economy classes, for instance.

As a result, if I know it should be a direct connection, I usually buy the exactly needed ticket from the airline directly.

Answer (score 0):

I always book using online travel sites and on many occasions found them to be cheaper than booking directly on the airline website. On the downside, not all travel sites allow you to enter a FF number to claim miles. Also, some airline websites allow you to choose a seat right after booking.

Comment: A travel agent is not really a travel website.

Comment: Also, you can (always?) claim miles by providing the Frequent Flyer Number on Checkin.